# What is the connection between the two words "battery" and "batter"?

Tags: meaning

Batter means to beat somebody very hard.

Battery is something that to store/provide energy.

Is there any connection between the two words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Etymonline* gives

**battery**(n.)

> (1530s) *"action of **battering**," in law, "the unlawful beating of another,"* from French batterie, from Old French baterie "beating, thrashing, assault" (12c.), from batre "to beat," from Latin battuere (see batter (v.)).

> Meaning shifted in French from "bombardment" ("heavy blows" upon city walls or fortresses) to "unit of artillery" (a sense recorded in English from 1550s). Extension to "electrical cell" (1748, first used by Ben Franklin) is perhaps from the artillery sense via notion of "discharges" of electricity. In Middle English, bateri meant only "forged metal ware." In obsolete baseball jargon battery was the word for "pitcher and catcher" considered as a unit (1867, originally only the pitcher).

Comment: "Battery" is commonly misused in electronics jargon.  Properly, a "battery" is an array of "cells", and is presumed to derive from an array of cannon as used by the military to "batter" an opponent's position.  So a "triple-A battery" is wrong -- should be a "triple-A cell".

Comment: Perhaps that triple-A object has several cells inside, making it a battery.  See https://archive.goughlui.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/DSC_9156-855x1024.jpg Admittedly, most triple-As are not like that nowadays.

Comment: When I was growing up, there were wet cells and dry cells. I had a dry cell, a big heavy tubular battery the size of a coke bottle, with brass screws for connection at the top. I forget what I used it for. In other European languages, electrical batteries are called _piles_, no doubt from the piling of cells atop one another.

Comment: @HotLicks -  I thought a triple-A battery was an installation of anti-aircraft artillery.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, that would work too.